# Mount failed (unknown file system) in virtualbox in ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 as host after installing GuestAdditions

Tags: virtualbox, mount, shared-folders, ubuntu-14.04

I am using virtual box 4.3.6 in Windows 7 PC. I am trying to run Ubuntu 14.04 .
After installing ubuntu since the display was low resolution i tried to install VirtualboxGuestAdditions I downloaded VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.10.iso and followed steps in question
 [mount gives unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'](https://superuser.com/questions/496513/mount-gives-unknown-filesystem-type-vboxsf)

Now I got optimum resolution but i am unable to mount the shared folder.

I used the command .

```
mount -t vboxsf sharedFolderName DestinationFolder
```

Now i am getting the error wrong fs type ..
I tried checking error using command

```
dmesg
```

and got

```
sf_read_super_aux err = -22
```

What I have done wrong ??
I have used the same method in fedora virtual image but with different VBoxGuestAddition version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching web a lot i got some info regrading this from VirtualBox.org itself.
In this new version of Guest Additions it has missed a symlink while installation.
This breaks the path of /sbin/mount.vboxsf so that the mount command fails.

Using this command i was able to fix the bug.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

Answer (score 6):

I've fixed mine using the following way:

1) Update system's packages

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

2) install virtual box guest additions (referenced from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/GuestAdditions))

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

3) Now install guest additional package (Crucial step! People generally miss this which creates an error “Unknown file type “vboxsf”)

```
$ apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

NOTES:

You might face the following problems:

- No such device:

  root@packer-virtualbox-iso:~/new# mount -t vboxsf new ~/new

  /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device

-> YOU HAVE TO RESTART TO ALLOW CHANGES TO TAKE EFFECT.

- you might experience the following error:

  vagrant@packer-virtualbox-iso:~$ sudo mount -t vboxsf new ~/new

  /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error

-> TO RESOLVE THIS, YOU MIGHT HAVE TO CHANGE THE NAME OF THE MOUNTING DEVICE/FOLDER (e.g. here is *new*)

-> OR FOLLOW THIS if NOT FIXED ([REF](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15497))

1. Made shared folder on host system, D:\Virtual Box\shared;
2. Ran VirtualBox;
3. Ran virtual machine;
4. Linux finished booting, I logged in;
5. I added shared folder D:\Virtual Box\shared, named it “shared”;
6. I made guest shared folder being logged as a user, called it “shared_folder”. /home//shared_folder;
7. $su;
8. Being logged as a root I mounted the shared folder: #mount -t vboxsf shared /home//shared_folder;
9. And all began to work.

May be the problem was host and guest folders should be the same names?

Comment: Thanks goodness! Why does this not have more upvotes??? Completely solves my problem with the Unknown file type “vboxsf” error when I had already installed VBox Additions!

Answer (score 0):

you don't mount the .is this way.

1. open virtual box main screen.
2. select your machine.
3. choose 'settings'.
4. select the 'storage' item.
5. one of the controllers should have a "disc" options, meaning DVD\CD drive, if not you can add one using the disc icon once selecting the controller (the one with the '+').
6. once you have one you can change the .iso file it's using in the 'attributes' section on the right.

Comment: @c0dd3 I have followed the same steps .
After adding the *.iso file I logged in to Ubuntu and installed VBOXlinuxAdditions. But Still Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

did not work (permission denied). Instead use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

This worked fine with Virtual box 6.2 and Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Answer (score 0):

How to make folder sharing from the start for working Ubuntu guest OS:

As of now (version 6.0.10 of VirtualBox) there are `make permanent` and `auto-mount` options for shared folder, also `mount point` (`At`) in GUI of virtualbox. For me the following worked:

1. On guest Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`
2. Add shared folder in GUI of VirtualBox.
3. Restart guest OS

Folder on mount point specified in GUI was created automatically and `ls` showed files located on host Windows PC.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your insights; the following worked for me:

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=tricia


# How to set up VirtualBox directory sharing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you get errors above you might have to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils

***Reload your Virtualbox
mkdir -p ~/Share_Guest
sudo mount -t vboxsf Share_Host ~/Share_Guest
```

If  you get an error like this:

*/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such file or directory*

you will have to make the guest directory manually using mkdir -p ~/Share_Guest