# VBox Guest Additions ISO can't be mounted because of VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, filesystems, mount

I am trying to run the command
`sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedUbuntuWindows SharedUbuntuWindows`
but I get the error `unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'`
on my guest Ubuntu machine. I am following [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/496513/mount-gives-unknown-filesystem-type-vboxsf) but I cannot find 'Install Guest Additions' under 'Devices'. Instead, I see 'Insert Guest Additions CD image'. Am I even on the proper path to solve the issue?

[image: Screenshot menu]

This is what I see when I select 'Insert Guest Additions CD image...'. Pressing 'Force Unmount' only makes the pop-up dialog disappear, but I still am unable to run the command `sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedUbuntuWindows SharedUbuntuWindows`.
[image: Screenshot error message]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Insert Guest Additions CD Image` is the same thing as `Install Guest Additions` in a different version of Virtual Box. That is the correct menu item. When you choose it, it will be as if you inserted an installation CD to your virtual machine. Run the appropriate setup program from the virtual CD drive.

Guest additions should include the software you need to use the vboxfs filesystem type.

EDIT: Based on your updated question, the real cause error you are seeing is `VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED`. Googling for that produces the answer in the first result: http://maheshhika.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/virtual-box-verr_pdm_media_locked/

Essentially, you need to unmount your virtual cd drive before inserting the guest additions cd image. The linked article provides instructions for doing this. Hitting the 'Force Unmount' button would be another way to unmount your drive, and after doing that the insert guest additions cd menu option should work the second time you use it.

Keep in mind that you not only have to insert the virtual cd, but actually run the installer before the `vboxfs` filesystem type will work.

Answer (score 35):

All the answer say to go via GUI and "Leave emtpy" the CD drive, but that wasn't working for me: still `VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED` error.

In my case I updated my macOS, I was forced to upgrade Virtualbox to 5.2 (I installed without uninstalling first). And now I get reported (by [vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) ) that I need an updated version of *GuestAdditions*.

The plugin wasn't able to update it. Every reload was always finding the old one (5.1; installed on VirtualBox 5.1).

I tried all the solution on the net and couldn't make it work via GUI (like all the other answers).

**VirtualBox was NOT able to really mount** the `GuestAdditions.iso` image automatically via the *"Device -> Insert GuestAdditions CD Image..."*.

So I did

```
sudo su
cd /media
mkdir cdrom
mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
```

Finally I got it mounted! Then just go into the mounted dir (`cd cdrom`) and exec the installer with `sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` (remember you are *root*).

And I finally got it mounted without the annoying `VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED` error!

[Tags: *osx,macbook,mac*]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/397973

Comment: This solution helped me. Initially, I did `apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils` in the guest Ubuntu, but it didn't help me. Running `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` helped. It looks like `virtualbox-guest-utils` and `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` are not the same thing.

Comment: That's right. IIRC, `virtualbox-guest-utils` is a repo with scripts for automatically taking care of mounting the `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` image to `/cdrom`, taking care of differences in interfacing with different operative systems, and running the installer `cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` when it is available. Probably also something more  Glad it helped you out!

Comment: @Emm I guess you forgot the relevant part of the suggestion

Answer (score 16):

just spent some time trying to fix it. This question is old, but maybe my answer serves someone.

A very easy way that I discovered to fix VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED for guest additions with a ubuntu guest and windows 10 host is:

1. Shut down (not save state) your virtualbox
2. Right-click on your machine in the virtualbox manager -> settings
3. Click on storage
4. Right-click on the cd drive and "remove attachment"
   [image]
5. After removing, click on the little CD symbol next to "Controller: IDE"
6. Choose "leave empty"

Now you restart your machine and click "devices"->"Insert guest additions" and it works

Cheers.

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you.

Comment: This was the solution, even in 2022 (for Ubuntu 14.04) on Win 10 64. Thank you, thank you, than you for taking the time to post this answer!!!

Answer (score 3):

The solution below worked for me:

- Select "**Cancel***"
- Go to "**Devices**" menu -> "**CD/DVD Devices**" -> "**Choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file...**" -> select "VBoxGuestAdditions.iso" from the Oracle/VirtualBox installation directory.

---

(*) Clicking on "***Force Unmount***" had no effect, in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

Is there. From console type:

```
> sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I was facing the same problem and the solution was simple that open the virtual machine OS and the after opening it open its display setting and the change the resolution accordingly this will fill the screen in background completely.

Answer (score -1):

Prerequisite: Before starting the virtual box instance, you have to go to `Settings > Storage` and add the guest additions ISO as an optical drive.

The problem happens when we select `Devices > Insert guest additions CD image`. But instead, if you go to `Devices > Optical Drives`, you'll see the guest additions ISO. Simply select it and it'll automatically prompt you and run the installation.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why the downvote? This solution worked for me when all other solutions didn't.